# Implementing burst mode control in a continuous PWM switching scheme

Tags: pwm, switching, burst

I am designing an inductive adder with two modules where a low-side MOSFET operates under continuous PWM switching in each module. However, my intended application for this adder would require programmable burst operation (programmable burst frequency) at some point. For example, the adder is designed to operate at 1-5 kHz continuous switching with a burst frequency around 100 Hz. At present, the MOSFETs are triggered using PWM signals from a 4-channel function generator. Any suggestion would be appreciated regarding implementing burst-mode control in the said scheme.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what an ‘inductive adder’ is. The control scheme would be simple to implement using an Arduino methinks.